# can't create project using react-native init

Tags: react-native

I am getting this error again and again when creating a new project using react-native init. I reinstalled react-native cli and tried again but no luck. Can someone please tell me is there anything I can do?

[image]

I have following versions installed
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.56.0
node: 10.6.0
npm: 6.1.0

Comment: It was working fine day before and all sudden stopped working

Comment: `line 30 in CliEntry.js`, why is it `import type {....} ...`? Shouldn't it be `import {...} ....`?

Comment: didn't you configure babel properly, seems babel issue.

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner.Can you please refer me some sources to solve this. I didn't find anything on google about this

Comment: I was using until yesterday, today the same error has started...

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be resolve in one line code nothing more

`$ react-native init [projectName] --version react-native@0.55.4`

what this does is that you explicitly tell that you want your project to be created with this specify version

Answer (score 1):

This error is may be because of react native version React native 0.56

Here is the link about the discussion of this issue [React native 0.56.* - "Unexpected identifier"](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20015)

So they suggest us to downgrade the version of react-native [React Native Version List](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/versions)

So open the file of your project named as `package.json`

inside it you can find `react-native": "0.56.4"`  replace this version with `react-native": "0.55.4"` or what ever the version you want

then save the file

go to the terminal or power sell

rich to the your project directory and run the command `npm-install`

after installation check the version of `react-native` by running the command `react-native --version` and make sure that version is which you changed in `package.json`

restart your project and you are ready to go without this error

Comment: It may be. But we need to upgrade at least to version 0.56 to be able to publish updated apps to Google play store. As from 1st of November it will allow to submit only apps that uses 26 API version.