# Unexpected Token Import React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have been following the steps provided by Facebook and got these errors when I tried to `react-native init AwesomeProject`

```
C:\Windows\system32\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\cliEntry.
js:30
import type {CommandT} from './commands';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Module._compile (C:\Windows\system32\AwesomeProject\node_modules\pirates\
lib\index.js:91:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (C:\Windows\system32\AwesomeProject\node_module
s\pirates\lib\index.js:96:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
```

How can I fix this error ? Been googling but of no help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634198/node-error-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import)

Comment: RN v56 is on problem, installing v54 or lower

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51246876/6359528