# Why doesn't react-native init work properly?

Tags: javascript, react-native

When I run `react-native init sth` the iOS and android folders don't get created. For any react-native commands I get the error below: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zuMu.jpg)
What's wrong?

Comment: `import` is not yet fully suported in nodejs

Comment: Suggest you go thru their official documentation on installation: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started

Comment: What is your version of node?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51246876/6359528   check my answer on it

Comment: I'm using Node 9.5 @bennygenel

Comment: Everything is set up. I used to do this with no problems before. @Isaac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a known bug with react-native 0.56 and the solution is to use an old version!
This is how I had to init my project:

```
react-native init {proj_name} --version react-native@0.55.4
```