# Troubles after upgrading react-native to 0.56

Tags: reactjs, facebook, react-native

i have troubles updating the new version of react-native which appears to improve vastly and a lot of features.

After reading this article :
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2018/07/04/releasing-react-native-056

I've started to run this command : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html

All goes well, the application is built after running `react-native run-ios`

The problem is the bundle which is buggy :

> node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start "--reset-cache"
>   Scanning folders for symlinks in
>   /Users/julestruong/Dev/BAP/flex/v1/flex-mobile-app/node_modules (14ms)
>   warning: the transform cache was reset.
>
> Cannot find module 'metro/src/transformer'
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! flex@0.0.1 start:
>   `node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start
>   "--reset-cache"` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at
>   the flex@0.0.1 start script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem
>   with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

Tries :

- remove node_modules
- start --reset-cache
- delete package-lock.json and reinstall.

Nothing works ...

Comment: Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51246876/6359528

Answer (score 0):

If you're using typescript you'll need to upgrade `react-native-typescript-transformer` to `1.2.10` since metro moved the transformer it relies on.